# Send email with .SentOnBehalfOfName

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a script that the company has been using for a while and no issues.

We switched from Outlook 2010 to Outlook 2016.

The script fills in the right information but when clicking on the send button, it bounces back to the email user's inbox saying "undelivered" and

> "This message could not be sent. You do not have the permission to send the message on behalf of the specified user."

I have verified that the user has full access to that user mailbox.

```vb
Sub ForwardA()

Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

Dim GetSMTPAddress As String, s As String, piece As String, i As Long, j As Long

Dim olkSnd As Outlook.AddressEntry, olkExu As Outlook.ExchangeUser
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objITEM = GetCurrentItem()
Set olkSnd = objITEM.Sender
If olkSnd.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then
    Set olkExu = olkSnd.GetExchangeUser
    GetSMTPAddress = olkExu.PrimarySmtpAddress
Else
    GetSMTPAddress = objITEM.SenderEmailAddress
End If
Set olkSnd = Nothing
Set olkExu = Nothing
s = GetSMTPAddress
i = InStr(s, "@")
j = InStrRev(s, ".")
piece = UCase(Mid(s, i + 1, j - i - 1))
If piece = "--------" Then
    piece = InputBox("----- - Enter New Company name")
End If
'MsgBox piece
Set objMail = objITEM.Forward
objMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "orders@------.com"
objMail.To = ""
objMail.Subject = piece & ": CONFIRMATION RECEIPT OF "
objMail.BCC = ""
objMail.SendUsingAccount = olNS.Accounts.Item(1)
objMail.Display
Set objITEM = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
MoveToCustomerPO
```

Comment: Possibly the default account is no longer account 1. Delete the line `objMail.SendUsingAccount = olNS.Accounts.Item(1)`.